# Cannot install electron in Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, electron

My npm version is 3.10.10

And node version is v7.2.1

And when I tried to install electron in ubuntu via :

```
sudo npm install electron --save-dev
```

I get error like this :

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:572:26)
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/dotmark/package.json'
npm WARN dotmark No description
npm WARN dotmark No repository field.
npm WARN dotmark No README data
npm WARN dotmark No license field.
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-87-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "electron" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! node v7.2.1
npm ERR! npm v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! electron@1.4.13 postinstall: node install.js
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@1.4.13 postinstall script 'node install.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the electron package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! node install.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR! npm bugs electron
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls electron
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /home/dotmark/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Why are you running `npm` as root when you aren't installing a module globally?

Comment: I guess you don't have `package.json` file. `--save-dev` flag adds the installed packages to the json file after installing. Try creating the `package.json` file.

Comment: would you suggest where to add the file..

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a module to the dependencies of the package you are writing (`--save-dev`) unless you first create a package (with `npm init` or by manually writing a `package.json`).

… but don't make the root of your package your own home directory. Create a directory for it.